# How can I make all tmux panes have their own unique shell history?

Tags: bash, tmux

Preface: My current tmux configuration has multiple panes in multiple windows in multiple sessions.

The problem that keeps arising is that when I work in one window, all my history is good and separate between that window's panes, and when I swap windows/sessions, that history is initially separate too, but only until I enter one command in a different window/session.

Once that happens, all the history for all panes gets merged together and it's sometimes impossible to find a certain pane's actual last command, depending on how long it had been since I was on the pane.

Is there any way to avoid this and have each pane have its own shell history?

Comment: Are you referring to the history for the shell(s) running under tmux?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using the `bash` shell, your command history is written to a file defined by the `HISTFILE` variable, which defaults to `~/.bash_history`. Inside a `tmux` pane, you have access to the variable `$TMUX_PANE` which looks something like this:

```
$ echo $TMUX_PANE
%3
```

You could use this to create a per-pane history by adding something like this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
if [[ $TMUX_PANE ]]; then
  HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history_tmux_${TMUX_PANE:1}
fi
```

This will store the history for pane 2, for example, in `~/.bash_history_tmux_2`.

The downside to this idea is that you're going to end up with a bunch of `.bash_history_tmux_*` files in your home directory.